# Ignore "This site can’t provide a secure connection" on Chrome - doesn't adhere to security standards. ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

A few months ago, I was able to access insecure https websites via chrome by clicking on advanced and "ignore" the error. But now I'm getting the following error on websites I'm developing on. There's no way to ignore them anymore.

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> xxxxx.com doesn't adhere to security standards.
>   ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT

I developing on these sites and sometimes the SSL certs aren't configured poperly on dev environments. It would be ideal to just ignore these errors during development while using chrome.

How can we ignore these insecure https sites so we can access them again? FYI, http isn't going to work as it auto redirects to ssl.

Comment: This error message means OpenSSL failed to parse your certificate. The connection _can't_ proceed until you actually fix your certificate. This question would be answerable if you included a copy of the broken cert.

Comment: Or in other words: This certificate is not "insecure" in terms of untrusted issuer (like with self-signed) or subject not matching domain from URL. This certificate is invalid in that it does not adhere to the standards. If you search for this error you get for example [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715969) where somebody declared the certificate as X.509 version 2 but included X.509 extension which were only defined with X.509 version 3.  And while you might skip insecure certificates you cannot skip invalid ones.

Comment: I have had this happen only in recent releases in Chrome even when Safari, Firefox, and MSIE have no issue with the web site in question (mine, locally i.e. on my LAN).  The worst part is that Chrome doesn't even tell you *WHAT* is causing this diagnosis; it would be nice to have a log.  It's an OpenSSL error code (ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT) but *WHY*?

Comment: By the way, this error might be occurring because the CA which signed the certificate is self-signed.  In theory, the only CA that is self-signed is a root CA and only down-stream CAs sign user certificates (E.g. web servers).  However, again, Firefox, Safari, and MSIE are tolerant; Chrome should be too if the CA certificate is imported into the browser as "Trusted Authority".

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? - I am getting this on proxy sites that open fine in Safari but shot this error in Google Chrome, I am happy to proceed with an unsecure connection but I can't find a way to ignore this error.

Comment: @Hackeron try brave.com